# Return False - Link Not working - Drop Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ok so i have a javascript drop down menu.  The drop down menu works fine but when i click one of the drop down links the link does not work.  I think it has something to do with my "return false/true" set up.

Javascript:

```
function ddMenu_open(event)
{
   ddMenu_close();
   var submenu = $(this).find('ul');
    if(submenu){
        ddmenuitem = submenu.css('visibility', 'visible');
        return false;
    }
   return true;
}

function ddMenu_close()
{  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden'); }

function ddMenu_timer()
{ closetimer = window.setTimeout(ddMenu_close, timeout); }

function ddMenu_canceltimer()
{  if(closetimer)
   {  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
      closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function()
{  $('#ddMenu > li').bind('click', ddMenu_open);
   $('#ddMenu li ul').bind('click', ddMenu_timer);

});

document.onclick = ddMenu_timer;
}
</script>
```

So when i remove the "return false" statement my links work but then my drop down menu doesn't stay open. When i remove the return false statement, the drop down menu will open real quick and then shut (barely giving the user time to click an item).  What do i need to change in this code so that when i click on the drop down it stays open and then when one of the drop down items/links are click the link actually works.

Again, right now the drop down functionality works fine (when it is click it stays open until there is another click) but when i click on the drop down item the link does not work, new page doesn't load.  Thank you for your help.

thanks for the responses but it's still not working for me.  Here is my entire code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ddMenu() {
var timeout    = 500;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function ddMenu_open(e)
{
   ddMenu_close();
   var submenu = $(this).find('ul');
    if(submenu){
        ddmenuitem = submenu.css('visibility', 'visible');


    }

}

function ddMenu_close()
{  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden'); }

function ddMenu_timer()
{ closetimer = window.setTimeout(ddMenu_close, timeout); }

function ddMenu_canceltimer()
{  if(closetimer)
   {  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
      closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function()
{  $('#ddMenu > li').bind('click', ddMenu_open);
   $('#ddMenu li ul').bind('click', ddMenu_timer);


});

document.onclick = function(ev){
    if(ev.target.nodeName !== 'ul')  {
        ddMenu_close();
    }
};


}
</script>
```

again i want the drop down menues to close when the document is click except for when the menu itself is clicked.  Thanks.

Comment: Setting up a jsfiddle of your code would be helpful.

Comment: Seems like `document.onclick = ddMenu_timer;` is starting the timer every time you click.

Comment: `var submenu = $(this).find('ul');  if(submenu){}`  This should be `if(submenu.length){}`.  jQuery always returns an object (even if it has no elements).  `if([])` and `if($())` are both true.

Comment: even when i remove document.onclick = ddMenu_time; the links still do not work.

Comment: Your indentation/braces style is really horrible.

Comment: Rocket- Even after i add the .length the links still do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning false you could try to just prevent the default behaviour of the pulldown menu like this:

```
function ddMenu_open(event)
{
   ddMenu_close(e);
   var submenu = $(this).find('ul');
    if(submenu){
        ddmenuitem = submenu.css('visibility', 'visible');
        return false;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
   return true;
}
```

**Note**: You don't need to declare an argument in ddMenu_open and you don't need to return true at the end of ddMenu_open. But I understand where you are coming from. This book by the way will get you up to speed: http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Comment: I believe the function definition should be: `function ddMenu_open(e)`  if you are using `e.preventDefault`.

Comment: Try and put ddMenu_close(e) outside of ddMenu_open (there is no reason of the function beeing inside another function, actually I just noticed that all of your code are functions inside a function.)


I could help you if you could provide me with a link to the whole document. It'd clearer to us what you are trying to achieve if we saw all the libraries you are using and the markup.


@Rob (e) is refering to ddMenu_close(e) not ddMenu_open()